# Cannot find my mistake with jQuery autocomplete and Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

**router**

```
  resources :pcps  do
    collection do
      get 'autocomplete'
    end
  end
```

**Controller**

```
def autocomplete
    @pcps = Pcp.order(:last).where("last like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
    render json: @pcps.map(&:full_name)
end
```

**View**

```
= f.text_field :pcp, data: {autocomplete_source:  '/pcps/autocomplete'}
```

Coffee script

> This code works. I am able to see the list and select one.

```
jQuery ->
  $('#sched_pcp').autocomplete
    source: ["Atest", "Btest","Ctest","Dtest","Btest1","Btest2"]
```

> This code does not work. The list is not being displayed even dough if for instance I curl localhost:3000/pcps/autocomplete?term=L I get the list in Jason format.

```
jQuery ->
  $('#sched_pcp').autocomplete
    source: $('#sched_pcp').data('autocomplete-source')
```

I am using ruby 2.2 and rails 4.2
The url '/pcps/autocomplete' returns the correct data.
Can someone help me see my mistake please? or maybe give me an idea how to debug it.

Comment: Just saying "This code does not work." will not allow us to help you. HOW does it not work? Is an error thrown? Does is run and behave differently from how you expect?

Comment: Where are you storing the data in `$('#sched_pcp').data('autocomplete-source', data);`?... because I'm guessing that `$('#sched_pcp').data('autocomplete-source')` is empty.

Comment: This code give me no indication of failure I have been using the browser console for that. I am expecting to have a list of names from where to choose. I did insert byebug in the autocomplete action and I can see it work.
Also if I type in the path in the browser I get the jason version of the list of names.

Comment: The truth is that I failed to explained the problem I am feeling the pressure ! I am trying to use the autocomplete  jquery plugin and it is not  displaying the selection list on the from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**In your gemfile**

```
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
```

bundle install

**In your application.js**

```
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

**In your controller**

```
autocomplete :model_name, :column_name, :full => true
```

**In your routes**

```
resources :controller_name do
  get :autocomplete_model_name_column_name, :on => :collection
end
```

**In your view**

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'column_name', '', autocomplete_model_name_column_name_controller_name_path %>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that I needed to see the output of the jQuery autocomplete, so proceeded to install a copy of the source and put some debugger statement... And like magic it worked.

There is something I do not quite like about this but what the heck it is working and I do not have the time keep diggin. I hope it does not bite me later.

BTW I did try the autocomplete gem before doing the debug with the same results.